# YAML need to use # inside but not comment it

Tags: gitlab, yaml, cicd

I need to use this code inside a YAML file to remove chars from a file, but on YAML `#` is comment and cannot execute all after the `#`

Example of what I want to execute: `echo $(tr -d '[\[\]#,"]')`

Is there any workaround to achieve want I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest, probably, in you case, would be to use a [folded block style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#813-folded-style), because your `tr` does have simple and double quotes in it, and going with a quoted string would need you to go in escaping characters, which could be a pain.

But for the sake of completeness, here are the possible ways:

```yaml
foo: "# I am not a comment, as I am enclosed in double quoted string"
bar: '# me neither, as I am enclosed in a single quoted string'
baz: |
  # so ain't I, in a literal style block
qux: >
  # I don't differ from the three above, in a folded style block
```

So, in your case, what you could do is:

```yaml
my_command: >-
  echo $(tr -d '[\[\]#,"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a matter of YAML syntax. You can enclose your command in single or double quotes and escape inner quotes using a backslash
(`\`)

For example, using single quotes and using `\'` to escape the literal inner single quotes:

```yaml
script:
  - 'echo $(tr -d \'[\[\[]#,"]\')'
```

Or the same with double quotes:

```
script:
  - "echo $(tr -d '[\[\]#,\"]')"
```

You can also use the other string styles that don't require escaping as described in another answer.